# Save related child model fields from parent - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have these models:

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    fieldrelated1 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel2', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel2')
    fieldrelated2 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel3', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel3')
    fieldrelated3 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel4', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel4')

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModel3(models.Model):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModel4(models.Model):
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

What I need, is when I save a record from `MyModel1`, create automatically an object on `MyModel2, MyModel3 and MyModel4`. With some filled fields with data from the parent.

So far, I have this:

```
def create_child_records(instance, created, rad, **kwargs):
    if not created or rad:
        return

    if not instance.fieldrelated1_id:
        fieldrelated1, _ = MyModel2.objects.get_or_create(field1=field2)
    instance.fieldrelated1 = fieldrelated1

    if not instance.fieldrelated2_id:
        fieldrelated2, _ = MyModel3.objects.get_or_create(field1=field3)
    instance.fieldrelated2 = fieldrelated2

    if not instance.fieldrelated3_id:
        fieldrelated3, _ = MyModel4.objects.get_or_create(field1=field4)
    instance.fieldrelated3 = fieldrelated3

    instance.save()

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_child_records, sender=MyModel1, dispatch_uid='create_child_records')
```

But when I try to save from parent it throws me:

```
name 'field2' is not defined
```

This method is at the end of the parent model, unindented, if I indent it, it throws:

```
ValueError: Invalid model reference MyModel1. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'
```

If I enclose the sender model (MyModel1) between `''` like:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_child_records, sender='MyModel1', dispatch_uid='create_child_records')
```

It throws:

```
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'MyModel1'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the `field2` is not defined in your signals. That is , you are trying to assign a variable which is not defined yet in your context/scope

Comment: But I can use 'name' for example, the thing with name is that it is not defined actually in the model, how can I define them in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is explicit enough. Have you tried this:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_child_records, sender='myapp.MyModel1', dispatch_uid='create_child_records')
```

Also the function `create_child_records` contains many errors: wrong field names, undefined variables.